# How to configure databricks to use correct connection string for dev and prod environments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, databricks, azure-databricks

I have 2 environments dev and prod in databricks. All my dev work is completed and I deployed to prod through devops but is showing my dev connection string to my sql database in the notebook.
How do I configure my databricks cluster to use my prod sql DB connection string and not dev? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.
I created separate jobs in databricks on both dev and prod, and added the parameters for each environment to the jobs, this way, if I run my dev job, it should use my dev connection strings and my prod job should use my prod connection strings in the widgets. This way I don't need to modify my notebook in my prod environment after deploying through CI/CD
[Jobs in databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/jobs/jobs)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use an Azure Key Vault Backed Secret Scope and store the conneciton string of your database in it and retrieve it with dbutils.

```py
connection_string = dbutils.secrets.get(scope='my_scope', key='database_connection_string')
```

You can see it as an analogy of Environment Variables :

- In your dev environment, you set the secret of the development Key vault to the connection string of the dev environment.
- In you production environment, you set it to the connection string of your prod database.

Comment: Thanks @Axel, I have this set up already in dev, I deployed through devops pipeline and I have same notebook on prod. I don't want to update the connection string in prod manual because every time I make changes, I have to update it everywhere manually. I am looking for the most efficient way of automating this process. Thanks

Comment: If you put your connection string in the key vault, you only need to set it up once per environment.